# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded while working with .vue

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

I work with Chat.vue file and here is its code.

```
<div class="chat">

    <chat-messages> ssss</chat-messages>

    <form action=""> </form>
</div>

</template>

<script>

    export default{
        //
    }

</script>
```

Here is code in app.js

```
Vue.component('chat', require('./components/chat/Chat.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And then I get this error in page.

```
> at Watcher.get (app.js:34022)
>     at new Watcher (app.js:33998)
>     at mountComponent (app.js:33670)
>     at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (app.js:39251)
>     at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (app.js:41575)
>     at init (app.js:34945)
>     at createComponent (app.js:36392)
>     at createElm (app.js:36340)
>     at createChildren (app.js:36463)
>     at createElm (app.js:36368)
```

at watcher get.

```
 } else {
  throw e
}
```

at new watcher

```
  this.value = this.lazy
    ? undefined
    : this.get();
};
```

So I am trying to work with .vue files and I got this error when I try to show some code.. Any idea how I can solve it? Also I am trying to add real time chat to my project, and I got this error while applying the codes in this video https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/laravel-chatroom/1801.

Comment: Could you show your code? It seems like you are getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You are creating circular loop of updating and watcher

Comment: craig which part of my code i should show? and yeah its about loop.. how to solve it?

Comment: Just do not use watcher to modify watched variable. Use new, computed variable based on watched variable. Otherwise you always end up in loop.

Comment: how i can do these ?

Comment: anyone have some suggestions which i can do ?

Comment: Do you have any code inside the `export default{}`? Can you show it?

Comment: no i dont have but anyways i solved the problem guys. I deleted throw e and it fixed.. :)